# Issue css font-size responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have developed a web page HTML.I wanted to see the behavior of my elements on mobile with Google Chrome mobile emulator.

And I found weird things.

I have this code :

```
<div>
    <div>
        <span>config.alarm_vocal_lines_config[1].line_id</span>
        <span>1 </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>config.alarm_vocal_lines_config[1].audio_level_line_config</span>
        <div>
   <span>config.alarm_vocal_lines_config[1].audio_level_line_config.main</span>
            <input type="number" value="-90">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>

<div>
     <div>
        <span>config.alarm_vocal_lines_config[2].line_id</span>
        <span>2 </span>
     </div>
     <div>
         <span>config.alarm_vocal_lines_config[2].audio_level_line_config</span>
     </div>
     <br>
</div>

<div >
  <div >
    <span>config.alarm_vocal_lines_config[3].line</span>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

First problem : with this code, in the emulator, the third line is smaller then the other. 
[image: Image 1]

Why ? how to avoid it ?

Second problem, if I remove one char from the last line, every line become smaller :

[image: Image 2]

Can someone tell me why the style change and how avoid it?

Not sure if I've made myself clear. Please ask for further clarification.

I haven't any CSS

Comment: I have no CSS that's the problem

Comment: Add line height for text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add line height for your text.

```css
span {
   line-height: normal;
   font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add **!important**, your are not Overright any css.

Comment: @A. Rossi, Have you checked it.

Answer (score 0):

If its the font size you are concerned about, you could try pasting this into your CSS file (or create one, if you haven't got one)

```
span {

  font-size: 16px !important;

}
```